# Python string formatting?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have eight characters and wanted to write them on 2-inch whitespace of a report (paper print) and each of them will take 0.5 X 0.5 box space.

I tried to use tab and whitespace however when I write it into a database it strips out certain space (tab or whitespace) How can I do this in python?

```
Example: 
I have this string
str='12345678'
I wanted this string to fit in a 2-inch space and each character takes equal
    space.
First will be saved in database and then printed out through OpenOffice report
```

Comment: Give an example please.

Comment: You need to add more information. Why would "it" strip out tabs when you write the data to a database. And what is "it" in this case? For your printing, you a monospace font where all letters have the same size.

Comment: So You'd like to export the data from Python script to some text file. open it in some text editor and print it from there or send it directly to the printer from the script? If the second option: hoe?Are You using some module?

Comment: @C14L I don't know why but it strips out the certain space between characters  however when I put those space in single quote it keeps them all and fits but I don't want the single quotes to be visible  and all are the same font size

Comment: @KowalskiPaweł Paweł, I want to write to a database and print out on paper, I have a fixed length of string like 8 characters  and wanted to put space between characters and write them back to database

Comment: Maybe you talking about `stringwithspaces.replace("\t", "").replace(" ", "")`? This code will replace all whitespaces from your string. Then you can get any char like this: `stringwithspaces[0]` to print it out.

Comment: @doubleui it was not my question

Comment: What about image, generated by python?

Comment: what do mean by image?

Comment: Create image in python: white canvas 2x2 inches and put your numbers on it: char by char, with 0.5x0.5 with/height, change X and Y position as you need for right spaces for each of char. So you can be sure you will always have right result: with any font on any OS. Maybe it's not so easy and right solution :)

Comment: What is the database you are using? What is the type of the field you are writing to? How do you print out data from the database? How do you write to the database from script?

Comment: @Rahul PostegreSQL, char size 64, using OpenOffice and python code update query